# Avoiding memory error when using scipy.sparse.block_diag

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following code for creating a very large Jacobian, where I first define a Jacobian with respect to one third of the relevant vector, before this is then converted to a sparse matrix consisting of three of these sub-Jacobians in a block diagonal format. This "sub" Jacobian is created densely, to avoid issues when populating it via a for loop. This inside of the for loop can likely be ignored/treated as a black box, but I've included the full code snippet just in case

However, I'm having an issue where I run into the error “unable to allocate 6 gb for sparse.block_diag” even though I am running this code on a cluster and can create the far larger dense matrix just fine. Is there an easy fix I am missing to avoid this issue?

```
    J = np.zeros((nparts, 8*self.nnode))
    for elem in range(self.nelem):
        lnodes = self.elem2n[elem]
        lparts = self.elem2p[elem]
        lxc, lyc, lzc = self.xc[lnodes], self.yc[lnodes], self.zc[lnodes]
        lxpart, lypart, lzpart = xpart[lparts], ypart[lparts], zpart[lparts]
        for i in range(len(lnodes)):
            xl, xu = lxc[0], lxc[1]
            yl, yu = lyc[0], lyc[2]
            zl, zu = lzc[0], lzc[4]
            xpl = (lxpart - xl) / (xu - xl)
            ypl = (lypart - yl) / (yu - yl)
            zpl = (lzpart - zl) / (zu - zl)
            xcom = (xu - xl) / 1
            ycom = (yu - yl) / 1
            zcom = (zu - zl) / 1
            af = Amat.A[:,i]
            adfdx = Amat.A[:, 8 + i] * xcom
            adfdy = Amat.A[:, 16 + i] * ycom
            adfdz = Amat.A[:, 24 + i] * zcom
            ad2fdxdy = Amat.A[:, 32 + i] * xcom * ycom
            ad2fdxdz = Amat.A[:, 40 + i] * xcom * zcom
            ad2fdydz = Amat.A[:, 48 + i] * ycom * zcom
            ad3fdxdydz = Amat.A[:, 56 + i] * xcom * ycom * zcom
            J[lparts, 0*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(af, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 1*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(adfdx, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 2*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(adfdy, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 3*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(adfdz, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 4*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(ad2fdxdy, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 5*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(ad2fdxdz, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 6*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(ad2fdydz, xpl, ypl, zpl)
            J[lparts, 7*self.nnode + lnodes[i]] = cubic_mesh.__tricubic_eval(ad3fdxdydz, xpl, ypl, zpl)
    if lowmem:
        J = sparse.block_diag((J, J, J))
```

Comment: What "far larger dense matrix"? I don't see such a thing.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear- rather than larger in terms of number of elements, I meant larger in terms of memory footprint (the matrix J, which is populated within the for loop, but will comprise of largely zero values afterwards)

Comment: Too much code and not enough traceback to warrant a further look!   `block_diag` passes the task on to `bmat`, which builds a new `coo` sparse matrix from the combined `coo` attributes of the component arrays.  Have you converted `J` into a `coo` matrix before passing it to `block_diag`?

Comment: That seems to be working for now, thanks